# WP Simple Pie custom fields between 2 sites

Tags: php, wordpress, simplepie

I have 2 websites.  One of them I am using ACF to add custom fields to a custom post type "jobs", I have setup the custom field with the key "job_type" on the main site.  Then I added this to the functions file:

```
/** Add ACF fields to RSS **/
add_action('rss2_item', 'cup_rss2_job');
function cup_rss2_job() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $job_link_url = get_field('job_link', $post_id);

    if($job_link_url){
        echo "<job_link>{$job_link_url}</job_link>\n";
    }
}
```

When I visit the feed such as http://my-domain.com/jobs/feed/  I can see where I now I have access to the values with `<job_link>`.  However, on the site I am using SimplePie on (same server)  I get the following error:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [simplepie-error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 59, column 106
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

The function I am using to get the feed should be setup correctly, I know because I use a similar function for grabbing another feed on the same sites with a separate custom field.  This is my function I am using to `fetch_feed`

```
function cup_jobs_feed($limit, $offset) {  

    $feed = fetch_feed( 'http://my-domain.com/jobs/feed/' );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $feed) ):

        // Get a maximum of 1 item
        $maxitems = $feed->get_item_quantity( $limit );
        $items = $feed->get_items( $offset, $maxitems );

        foreach ( $items as $item ):

            $feedDescription = $item->get_content();
            $image = returnImage($feedDescription);
            $image = scrapeImage($image);
            $image_url= $item->get_permalink();
            $description = $item->get_description();
            $description = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $description); //strip img out of description
            $job_link = $item->get_item_tags('','job_link')[0]['data'];
            ?>
            <div class="row job-listing">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="image-box"><?php echo '<a href="' . $image_url . '"><img class="aligncenter" src="' . $image . '" /></a>'."\n";?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 job-details">
                    <h4><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <p><?php echo strip_tags($description); ?></p>
                    <p><?php
                        if($job_link){ ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $job_link; ?>" target="_blank" title="Click Here to Register">Learn More</a>
                        <?php
                        } else { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">Learn More</a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </p>   
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <?php
        endforeach; 
    else: // Returned WP_Error, unable to fetch the feed.
    ?>
        <p>There was an error fetching the CUP Jobs, please try again later</p>
    <?php
    endif;
    ?>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After running my feed through an XML validator I found that one of the `job_link` urls had '`&`' which XML needed this converted to html `&#038;` and that is what was causing the feed to throw the error message of invalid characters.

so in short, if I put this in my custom field on site #1 `http://google.com/view=mobile&location=1` this would fail.  The proper way should be this:

```
http://google.com/view=mobile&#038;location=1
```